# Codeigniter disable storing previous form data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

There is a Codeigniter scenario wherein the First form contains textarea, checkboxes.

After filling in user goes to 2nd page. There is button Previous to go back to 1st page.

The problem is 1st form's is populated with values set before.

*I would like to have a page without auto populating.*

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your navigator keep in cache your data, look to :

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```